# Limit based question (wanna know how to recognize such questions in first glance)

Tags: limits

$lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-sinx}{(tanx)^3}$

I have its solution,

### In the solution, $sinx$ and $tanx$ both are expanded (i think by mclaurin expansion; not sure)

I tried to solve it by L hospital rule but couldn't solve

Is there anyway to recognize such questions in first glance?

Comment: $x-\sin(x) \sim x^3/6$, $\tan(x)^3 \sim x^3$...

Comment: Can you use the rules of L'Hospital?

Comment: Yes i can use L'Hospital

Comment: Your parenthetical remark is (I think) the most reliable general method. Sometimes you can recognize a friend like $(\sin x)/x$. L'Hopital should be a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record, L'Hôpital's Rule also yields a limiting value of $1/6$.

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin x}{\tan^3x}
& = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{3\tan^2x\sec^2x} \\
& = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos^2x-\cos^3x}{3\tan^2x} \\
& = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{(2\cos x-3\cos^2x)(-\sin x)}{6\tan x\sec^2x} \\
& = \lim_{x\to0}\frac12\cos^5x-\frac134\cos^4x \\
& = \frac16
\end{align}

I'm not sure that there's any infallible detection algorithm for such questions, other than recognizing that all the terms have a fairly well-behaved MacLaurin series.  Sometimes it might be disguised in a trigonometric expression (though it isn't here), which can be "unlocked" by simplifying it, a little bit like I did in the L'Hôpital's Rule expansion above.

Comment: Thabk you..i got it

Answer (score 1):

Use the fundamental limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\tan x}x=1$$ , then you "get rid" of the tangent and then it is easy with L'Hopital.

Comment: Then i have to multiply and divide the tangent by $x^3$?

Comment: Ohh..i solved it this way, thank you.. (I don't know why they have given a long solution  in the book when it can be done this way)